# Complex folder structure using MVC 4 Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very large system divided by folders, like that:

```
Folder1 - Folder2 - Folder3 - View1/View2
Folder1 - Folder2 - Folder4 - View3
Folder1 - Folder2 - Folder5 - View4
Folder1 - Folder6 - Folder7 - View5/View6/View7
...
```

I´d like to know if it possible to create that folder organization with MVC 4... Areas just give 1 sub nivel...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom view engine which allows you to override the default views locations:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx
- http://blog.thekfactor.info/posts/asp-net-mvc-custom-view-engines-using-the-razor-view-engine-as-the-base/

Comment: So, Is that the only option? I have more than 100 folders... Am I supposed to mapping all of then in the custom view engine?

Comment: Yes, that's what you are supposed to do. Alternatively if you follow the standard conventions you won't need to write custom view engines.

Comment: How is it even possible to mantain a huge project organized with standard conventions? In my case, i will have 5 Areas, and then in Area 1, all Views will be grouped in the same level (about 100)...

Comment: 100 Views in the same level??????? You have 100 actions in a single controller? Just organize your controllers better - by resources. As you know, each view is placed in a subfolder with the name of the controller hosting the action that is serving this view.

Comment: No, I mean Controllers... In Area I have about 80 controllers... In my old Web Forms project I have organized with folder, sub-folders... But with MVC all in same folder...

Comment: You could place controllers wherever you want. ASP.NET MVC doesn't care. It is loading them at runtime by type from the AppDomain. It absolutely doesn't matter where your `XXXController.cs` file lives. They could even be placed in separate assemblies and logocally organized. What's important is the location of your views. But as I already said in my previous comment the location of the view is bound to the name of the controller. So if you have 5, 6 actions in a controller (which sounds reasonable) you will have at most 5 views in the corresponding folder.